# String Input of three numbers (comma seperated) doesn't work in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

So when I try to put in three numbers as a String in a usual setter-method, it doesn't work.
Does anybody know why?

```
function test(string memory x) public view returns(string memory){
    return x;

}
```

When I try: "1,2,3" I get an JSON Error, but when I try: "a,b,c" it does work perfect.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. I'd say it's a bug in Remix. I've seen a few bugs like this in the parameter parsing. Usually I can find a workaround syntax, but this time I'm stumped. File a bug?

Comment: A more general string which causes the problem is `"<a string of any characters except comma>,<a string of numeric characters only>,<a string of any characters>"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using "12,34" in REMIX IDE desktop mac version works. Using 12,34 however doesn't (as it should). I believe this bug has been fixed.